# Validate the order of elements in a string

Tags: php

I'm trying to validate if the user has entered the correct order, otherwise my script won't work.

The correct order is `jpg, jpeg, png, zip` but what the user might enter is `jpg,jpeg,png,zip`, which is wrong.

How can I validate if the correct order is entered?

Example of what I'm trying to archieve **(this will not work, it's pure for you to get an idea of what I'm trying to archieve, no it will not work and it's purely wrong and invalid code)**:

```
function randomizer_extensions_validate( $input ) {
    if(order == 'jpg, jpeg, png') {
         return $input;
    } else {
         echo 'you might want to correct that';
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(order == 'jpg, jpeg, png')` that will never work. You're best to set that up as an array and check to see if it is in that array.

Comment: @Fred-ii- what if user enters a string? Thought I don't know what for.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Something along the lines of that example.

Comment: @u_mulder I won't be a user so I won't do it. They'll have to take it up with council at the next board meeting.

Comment: Oh and `if(order` that is being treated as a constant here. I take it that what you posted is pseudo?

Comment: This seems like a simple string comparison. If it is something else, this questions needs to be edited.

Comment: I can't help but think this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Yes, but if it's a constant I don't see why he is doing a string comparison there..

Comment: Then again, I might have misinterpreted the question. *(Correct me if I'm wrong; I'm a big boy, I can take it).*

Comment: If you know what order should be - why user should enter it?

Comment: @Fred-ii- No no no, hold on. It's just a non working code which just demostrates how I want it to function. It's nothing which will work.

Comment: @Mitch make the question a bit more clear, will you?

Comment: @Mitch sounds to me and looking at both `jpg, jpeg, png, zip` `jpg,jpeg,png,zip` is that the first contains spaces and not the other and that you're looking to see if that string matches perfectly, correct?

Comment: @Fred-ii- You got it!

Comment: ^ well there you go guys, see [my comment;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399858/validate-the-order-of-elements-in-a-string#comment70001805_41399858) I have to leave.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

define('order', 'jpg, jpeg, png, zip');

function randomizer_extensions_validate($input) {
    if (order === $input)
        return $input;

    return false;
}

var_dump(randomizer_extensions_validate('jpg,jpeg,png,zip')); // returns false
var_dump(randomizer_extensions_validate('jpg, jpeg, png, zip')); // returns string 'jpg, jpeg, png, zip'

?>
```

This will compare the strings, and return false if not a match.